# Leaflet, Topojson and layergroup

Tags: leaflet, topojson

I have a geographic layer with three levels: village > county > region.

My topojson consists of polygons for the villages, and I have a json that contains the village > county > region data.

I load it this way:

```
L.TopoJSON = L.GeoJSON.extend({
  addData: function(jsonData) {    
    if (jsonData.type === "Topology") {
      for (key in jsonData.objects) {
        geojson = topojson.feature(jsonData, jsonData.objects[key]);
        L.GeoJSON.prototype.addData.call(this, geojson);
      }
    }    
    else {
      L.GeoJSON.prototype.addData.call(this, jsonData);
    }
  }  
});
var topoLayer = new L.TopoJSON();

var village =  {};

$.getJSON('data/villages_data.json', function(data) {
  village = data;
  $.getJSON('data/villages_geo.json').done(addTopoData);
});
function addTopoData(topoData){
  topoLayer.addData(topoData);
  topoLayer.addTo(map);
  topoLayer.eachLayer(handleLayer);
}
```

I would like to show on the map the three levels: village, county, and region. I've managed to use the layergroup before, and I was thinking of using that in order to add a control to switch each administrative level. 
I would like also to style each administrative level differently.

I would have liked to do it directly in the map.. otherwise the only solution I see is to make three shapefiles, one for each admin level, and then make one topojson for the three layers. Then I guess it would be easier to access each admin level; although I'm not even sure I would handle it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Kinda confused because i don't clearly understand your setup/explanation but from what i gather, here's what i would do. You could export your shapefile as three different GeoJSON files and convert them to one TopoJSON file:

```
topojson -o topo.json -- villages.json counties.json regions.json
```

Then on the clientside you could do this:

```js
var overlays = {
    'villages': new L.GeoJSON(null, {
        'style': function () {
            return {
                'color': 'red'
            }
        }
    }),
    'counties': new L.GeoJSON(null, {
        'style': function () {
            return {
                'color': 'green'
            }
        }
    }),
    'regions': new L.GeoJSON(null, {
        'style': function () {
            return {
                'color': 'blue'
            }
        }
    })
};

var control = new L.Control.Layers(null, overlays).addTo(map);

$.getJSON('topo.json', function (topo) {
    for (key in topo.objects) {
        var geo = topojson.feature(topo, topo.objects[key]);
        overlays[key].addData(geo);
    }
});
```

Some thing along those lines, but mind you: take it as pseudo/untested code because i wrote it freehand and haven't got a proper TopoJSON file by hand to actually test it.

Comment: Just for the record: `style` option can directly be an object. `L.geoJson` will convert it into a function that always returns that object.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and spotting the highlight error, didn't autodetect properly and oversaw it. As for the factory method, i always use the normal way with the `new` keyword in all my code/examples so i changed it back. It wouldn't be the first time i have to help someone who's got a problem with instanciating when they take for granted that a factory is present when it's not (like with some plugins etc)

Comment: Sure, Leaflet is good enough that the constructors and factories are equivalent. But not some plugins, as you say…

Comment: Thanks for the code, that's exactly I was talking about! That's what I had been thinking as a backup plan. So it works like that, but this means that I have to add three times the same borders, while I thought that the point of topojson was not to repeat borders. What I was trying to reproduce was the example from Mike Bostock: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4090848: he has only one layer and styles it with d3. Since my dataset is huge, I would rather minimise duplicates. Could we use leaflet to do what Mike does with d3? Styling and controlling the layers :)

Comment: Having no repeat borders is not the point of TopoJSON, it can do that to. You're overlooking the fact that he's using `topojson.mesh` instead of `topojson.feature` which is exactly what you are looking for: 'Returns the GeoJSON MultiLineString geometry object representing the mesh for the specified object in the given topology. This is useful for rendering strokes in complicated objects efficiently, as edges that are shared by multiple features are only stroked once.' https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference#mesh And yes this can be used in Leaflet too, why not? :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for indeed! I'll try to implement it next week, thanks :)